# Permission denied: '/var/lib/partman/stopfifo' when trying to install 14.04 as dual boot with Windows 8

Tags: 14.04, dual-boot, system-installation

I am trying to install UBUNTU 14.0.4.1 LTS along with Windows 8. I've followed this question and done all the neccesary steps,  [How do I install Ubuntu alongside a pre-installed Windows with UEFI?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/221835/installing-ubuntu-on-a-pre-installed-windows-8-64-bit-system-uefi-supported)

Specs:

- Toshiba p75-A7100
- Came installed with Windows 8.

I've done this:

- UEFI is enabled
- Secure boot is disabled

I am trying to install Ubuntu from a live CD. The installer gets stuck at `Prepare to Install phase` with below stack trace in debug.

```
(process:4250): dconf-CRITICAL **: unable to create file '/home/ubuntu/.cache/dconf/user': Permission denied. dconf will not work properly.

(process:4250): dconf-CRITICAL **: unable to create file '/home/ubuntu/.cache/dconf/user': Permission denied. dconf will not work properly.

(process:4250): dconf-CRITICAL **: unable to create file '/home/ubuntu/.cache/dconf/user': Permission denied. dconf will not work properly.

(process:4250): dconf-WARNING **: failed to commit changes to dconf: Could not connect: Connection refused

(process:4263): dconf-CRITICAL **: unable to create file '/home/ubuntu/.cache/dconf/user': Permission denied. dconf will not work properly.

(process:4263): dconf-CRITICAL **: unable to create file '/home/ubuntu/.cache/dconf/user': Permission denied. dconf will not work properly.

(process:4263): dconf-CRITICAL **: unable to create file '/home/ubuntu/.cache/dconf/user': Permission denied. dconf will not work properly.

(process:4263): dconf-WARNING **: failed to commit changes to dconf: Could not connect: Connection refused
update_release_notes_label()
update_release_notes_label()
/usr/lib/ubiquity/ubiquity/frontend/gtk_components/nmwidgets.py:18: Warning: Source ID 512 was not found when attempting to remove it
GLib.source_remove(self.timeout_id)
/usr/lib/ubiquity/ubiquity/frontend/gtk_components/nmwidgets.py:131: Warning: Source ID 578 was not found when attempting to remove it
GLib.source_remove(self.rows_changed_id)
Exception caught in process_line:
Traceback (most recent call last):
File "/usr/lib/ubiquity/ubiquity/filteredcommand.py", line 145, in process_line
return self.dbfilter.process_line()
File "/usr/lib/ubiquity/ubiquity/debconffilter.py", line 287, in process_line
if not input_widgets[0].run(priority, question):
File "/usr/lib/ubiquity/plugins/ubi-partman.py", line 2977, in run
size = int(parted.partition_info(p_id)[2])
File "/usr/lib/ubiquity/ubiquity/parted_server.py", line 220, in partition_info
self.open_dialog('PARTITION_INFO', partition)
File "/usr/lib/ubiquity/ubiquity/parted_server.py", line 141, in open_dialog
self.error_handler()
File "/usr/lib/ubiquity/ubiquity/parted_server.py", line 112, in error_handler
exception_type = self.read_line()[0]
File "/usr/lib/ubiquity/ubiquity/parted_server.py", line 74, in read_line
line = self.outf.readline().rstrip('\n')
File "/usr/lib/python3.4/codecs.py", line 313, in decode
(result, consumed) = self._buffer_decode(data, self.errors, final)
UnicodeDecodeError: 'utf-8' codec can't decode byte 0xd5 in position 66: invalid continuation byte
Exception ignored in: <bound method PartedServer.__del__ of <ubiquity.parted_server.PartedServer object at 0x7f86ed2fbf28>>
Traceback (most recent call last):
File "/usr/lib/ubiquity/ubiquity/parted_server.py", line 62, in __del__
self.close_dialog()
File "/usr/lib/ubiquity/ubiquity/parted_server.py", line 148, in close_dialog
self.sync_server()
File "/usr/lib/ubiquity/ubiquity/parted_server.py", line 132, in sync_server
with open(stopfifo, 'w'):
PermissionError: [Errno 13] Permission denied: '/var/lib/partman/stopfifo'
```

Comment: possible duplicate of [Installing Ubuntu on a Pre-Installed Windows 8 (64-bit) System (UEFI Supported)](http://askubuntu.com/questions/221835/installing-ubuntu-on-a-pre-installed-windows-8-64-bit-system-uefi-supported)

Comment: No it is not a duplicate issue. I know lot of things are valid on above link i have done all those steps. My issues is that the installer gets stuck at Preparing install stage. I dont think it has got anything to do with UEFI or secure boot. it is related to the disk and partitons i guess.

Comment: Have you tried downloading a new version of Ubuntu and do the install again? It could be a bug if it just gets *stuck*.

Comment: I created a live CD with one ubuntu image and tried. I did try with Linux Mint image and sadly it too gets stuck at same point. So i assume it is the issue with Partition.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok i want to post the solution here so some body else finds it useful..

The issues were

1. I cloned my orginal HDD to my new SSD for windows 8 and then tried to install UBUNTU on it. Not sure what happened but that triggered some permission issues that causes the Installer to crash. So dont create a clone of your windows 8 rather use a recovery or an orginal CD to create the partiotions and install windows.

2.once you are sure that windows boots up. Dont tamper with partitions you dont have to and also if using 14.0.4 LTS.. just disable fast boot. rest every other configurations on bios is fine.

3. follow this link

http://www.everydaylinuxuser.com/201...e-windows.html

And you are set . Am able to dual boot Ubuntu and windows and both works like charm.